# For a function to be continuous does it have to be in metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

For a function to be continuous  does it have to be in metric space?
in other words, does non metric space implies non continuity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can talk about continuity of a map $f:X\to Y$ so long as $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. We might say that $X$ is a topological space if it is equipped with a topology $\tau_1$, where $\tau_1$ is really just a subset of $\mathscr{P}(X)$, the power set of $X$. The sets in $\tau_1$ are called open and are closed under the operations of arbitrary union and finite intersection.

Then, we say that $f$ is a continuous function from $(X,\tau_1)\to (Y,\tau_2)$ if $U\in \tau_2$ implies $f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_1$. That is, the preimage of an open set in $Y$ is open in $X$.

So, to answer your question: no the sets $X$ and $Y$ do not need to be metric spaces - metric spaces are a specific example of topological spaces. Their topologies are determined by the metric chosen - as you have seen no doubt.